# translate asp.net core model Binding messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I'm trying to translate standard asp.net core messages but none of my attempts have been successful. In ASP.NET MVC we had a package which translated Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. {Language}, but in asp.net core I did not package package to do this so I chose to do as indicated in the documentation itself, but I did not succeed. Below code:

Method Register:

```
 public static void Register(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        #region aplication
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options => { options.AddNavigationBootstrap3Views(); });

        services.TraduzirMensagensModelValidation();

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddSingleton(provider => configuration);




        #endregion


        #region Presentation

        services.AddAuthentication(configuration);
        services.AddTransient<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Conta>, ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options => HelperAutorization.Register(options));

        services.AddCustonNavigation(configuration.GetSection("NavigationOptions"));

        #endregion
    }
```

Method TraduzirMensagensModelValidation:

```
public static class LocalizationModelValidation
{
    public static IServiceCollection TraduzirMensagensModelValidation(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x, y) => "O valor '{0}' não é válido para {1}.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingBindRequiredValueAccessor(x => "Não foi fornecido um valor para o campo {0}.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingKeyOrValueAccessor(() => "Campo obrigatório.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingRequestBodyRequiredValueAccessor(() => "É necessário que o body na requisição não esteja vazio.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "O valor '{0}' não é válido.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor(() => "O valor fornecido é inválido.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyValueMustBeANumberAccessor(() => "O campo deve ser um número.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "O valor fornecido é inválido para {0}.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => "O valor fornecido é inválido para {0}.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor(x => "O campo {0} deve ser um número.");
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(x => "O valor nulo é inválido.");
        }).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization().AddViewLocalization();

        return services;
    }
}
```

[image: not working]

Would anyone know any other way to translate these messages or if there is a .net standard / core package that translates these messages?

Note: I also tried with a resources file but translated the messages

Answer (score 0):

I would do it one of the worst ways possible, but it might work. If you take every message and save it as a string. This makes it possible to make a couple of IF statements that tests for the language. You can then make it read a TXT file that defines what each string means in different language. EXAMPLE: save the first message as UU001. Then define it in a TXT file reading: UU001 = "what the string means in the corresponding language".

Hope it helps a little.